# How to control the timing of first interstitial Ad in Android (Admob)?

Tags: android, admob

My app has a 3 page layout.  The first 2 pages contains list items and the 3rd page has a Media player.  I configured Admob's Interstitial video Ad on 'Page 2'.  I found out that my users are navigating 'Page 2' very quickly and the video Ad starts playing when they are in 'Page 3'.  This page has my app's media player, so the Ad ends up overlapping with my App's media content.

Due to the poor user experience, I see increased number of uninstalls nowadays.  I have already kept the Ad count to a minimum (1 Ad / 5 Hours).  But the Ad starts playing the very first time when the user is in 'Page 3'.  The user had just installed the App and is met with a poor experience.

Is there an option to control the timing of Interstitial Ads?  Say, the Ad should trigger only after the first 2 minutes (everytime when the user opens the App).

Comment: You can make sure the Ad is loaded from the first activity, and call the show function whenever you want.

Comment: Did you try handler post delayed?